# Create a Mac OS X 10.9 bootable USB flash drive on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: macos, ubuntu, liveusb

I have an ISO of Mac OS X 10.9 (Mavericks) and I want create a bootable USB stick with it, I have a USB with 16 GB.

I already did it on Mac OS X, and it was easy, but today I need do it on Ubuntu 13.10 machine, and I have no idea of how do it,

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: What did you try? Did you [ask google](https://www.google.com/search?q=ubuntu+bootable+osx+usb)?

Comment: @terdon i need do an osx usb bootable, and not a linux usb bootable, on osx i did like it http://arstechnica.com/apple/2013/10/how-to-make-your-own-bootable-os-x-10-9-mavericks-usb-install-drive/ but i need a way t do it on linux machine.

Comment: I know, my point was that on [su] as on all stack exchange sites, we expect the OP to show research, to first search how to do it and _then_ ask here. You seem to have not tried at all, just posted a question directly which is why I asked what you've tried. There are _loads_ of howtos on how to make a bootable USB using Linux, including making it boot OSX.

Comment: I have a 64bit osx lion pendrive here, but I've forgot how I made this. I am really sorry! But don't give up! It is possible, and wasn't complex!

Comment: http://www.pendriveapps.com/software/live-usb/

Comment: @terdon I`m a menber of superuser for 1 year and 7 months, and it is just my second question, so I did this question because I not found a solution alone, and I tried a lot.

Comment: @terdon that apps works to do linux or windows usb bootables, I not see anything for osx.

Answer (score 1):

In the above link there is a guide that I'm about to try with an older OSX.
[How to make a bootable OS X 10.9 Mavericks USB install drive on LINUX](http://www.insanelymac.com/forum/topic/293168-guide-how-to-make-a-bootable-os-x-109-mavericks-usb-install-drive-on-linux/).

It describes step by step how you can make a Mavericks USB installer on Linux without any running OS X and that requires:

> - empty USB stick of minimum size 8GB
> - copy of Mavericks
> - working Linux (virtualized is also OK) with following installed packages: hfsplus, hfsprogs, gparted, p7zip
> - at least 15GB free space on your system
> - and time :)

Comment: I can attest that this is a working method. I personally used it to setup my hackintosh boot on my machine.